# how does the inbuilt python function 'print' work in the stack/heap

Tags: python, memory, stack, heap-memory

So i was using a tracer to trace this program

```
1   def g(x):
2       y = 10
3       y = 2
4       return y + x
5   
6   def f():
7       y = 1  
8       return g(y)
9       
10  print(f())
```

And the program stopped tracing after the stack frames for functions f and g were exited. Does a stack for the built in function 'print' get created, and if so, what happens within that stack? Below I attached a picture of what a stage of the tracing process looks like (as you can see from how basic it is, I'm a novice), where the left side is the stack and the right side is the heap.
[image]

Comment: The tracer can only trace functions that are written in Python, not functions that are built into the interpreter.

Comment: It's running in C code, there's no Python stack for it.

Comment: @Barmar thx. so can you trace this inbuilt function for me? could you elaborate on what you meant by "python stack"?

Comment: Built-in functions are black boxes, unless you run python in a debugger like gdb.